# I can't see anything in my render

Tags: rendering

So this is the default project. No anything expect transformed the default cube a bit.

When I press render as in the pic that's what I see.

I have run the normal google fixes to no avail.

Camera is selected and looks at the cube, Lightning is on but nothing.

It has to be noted that my other projects have the same problem and I have reset the factory settings to try and fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Have you actually rendered your image via F12 or the Render > Render Image menu? You should see 'Render Result' in the centre of the top menu bar and the time and memory used at the top-left immediately after rendering.

Comment: I was up until 12:30 working on a model and missed the most important thing. Press F12 

I am sorry for wasting you time.

Comment: Ah! Yes. That does help! :^))